# Can a two Kanji character word ever have the same meaning if written in reverse order?

Tags: words

I am asking this question because it might be possible for two Kanji characters, if written in reverse order, could have the same meaning. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can think of 心身 and 身心, so I would say yes sometimes. @naruto's answer is really good as he has many examples...more examples than I can think of.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually reversing the order drastically changes the meaning even if it happens to mean something:

> - 会社【かいしゃ】 company ≠ 社会【しゃかい】 society
> - 牛乳【ぎゅうにゅう】 cow milk ≠ 乳牛【にゅうぎゅう】 milk cow
> - 現実【げんじつ】 reality ≠ 実現【じつげん】 realization
> - 家出【いえで】 running away from home ≠ 出家【しゅっけ】 entering the priesthood
> - 日本【にほん】 Japan ≠ 本日【ほんじつ】 today

But some pairs have a very similar meaning, if not completely interchangeable. Examples include:

> - 表裏【ひょうり】 ≒ 裏表【うらおもて】 two sides (eg of a paper)
> - 性根【しょうこん】 ≒ 根性【こんじょう】 nature (of a person), character
> - 階上【かいじょう】 ≒ 上階【じょうかい】 upper floor
> - 年毎【としごと】 ≒ 毎年【まいとし】 every year
> - 誕生【たんじょう】 ≒ 生誕【せいたん】 birth
> - 野山【のやま】 ≒ 山野【さんや】 hills and fields
> - 事物【じぶつ】 ≒ 物事【ものごと】 things
> - 苦労【くろう】 ≒ 労苦【ろうく】 hardship
> - 左右【さゆう】 ≒ 右左【みぎひだり】 left and right
> - 凹凸【おうとつ】 ≒ 凸凹【でこぼこ】 unevenness
> - 祖先【そせん】 ≒ 先祖【せんぞ】 ancestor

Comment: Worth pointing out to the reader if they are unaware that the nuance or context of the reversals even when the meaning doesn't change very much is different, to some degree because of the on/kun-yomi shift.

Answer (score 1):

Ever?  Yes.  日日 has the same meaning forward and reverse.

Comment: Also, I understand that in some contexts phrases may be written right-to-left - effectively, in the traditional top-to-bottom, then right-to-left manner, but with a single character per "line".

Comment: humor is strong in this one