# Difference between 始終 and 終始?

Tags: word-choice

Amusingly enough, it seems like by swapping the kanji in 始終 you can get a slightly different word. What is the difference between the two of them? I found some answers on Japanese sites but reading them I feel like I'm just going through a bunch of synonyms and very similar descriptions. An English answer would really help...

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48910/what-is-the-term-for-two-kanjis-that-when-written-in-reverse-have-the-same-me/48927#48927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

始終（しじゅう） is relatively rare in modern Japanese, except that a four-kanji compound [一部始終](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E5%A7%8B%E7%B5%82) is common. Standalone 始終 mainly appears in stiff literary works as an adverb meaning "all the time". If I heard 始終 in conversation, I might not understand it.

終始（しゅうし） is much more common than 始終. It can also mean "all the time" or "always", but I think it tends to mean "from beginning to end (of a certain event, etc)" more often. 終始 is also a suru-verb. ～に終始する is a common phrase meaning "to do only ～ from beginning to end."

> 会合は終始よいムードだった。
>   The meeting was in a good mood from beginning to end.
>
> スピーチの中で、彼は弁解に終始した。
>   In his speech, he entirely focused on making excuses.