# Is there a word to refer to those pairs (or sets) of words that are made up of the same kanji but in the opposite order?

Tags: words

I find such thing very interesting as it is a phenomena that simply does not exist for languages that do not use kanji or similar writing systems. Is there a way to call such pairs of words? For example:

> 会社 / 社会
>
> 海外 / 外海
>
> 旅行 / 行旅
>
> 貸借 / 借貸

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48910/what-is-the-term-for-two-identical-kanjis-that-when-written-in-reverse-have-t/48927#48927 may contain helpful information.

Comment: Thank you @JACK, it's funny because the answer you posted is an actual answer of my question, but not of your original one... lol.

Comment: I provide helpful information but am not yet proficient enough to provide detailed answers!

Comment: hat's not my fault... [JACK added `identical` almost one year later](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/48910/revisions), which made my answer look pretty out-of-place :D Perhaps we can revert his edit and mark this question as the duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: I see! let's mark this question as duplicated.