# 装着 vs 着装? Souchaku vs Chakusou

Tags: meaning, word-choice, kanji, nuances, kanji-choice

Both are used to mean equip right?

Any difference in meaning or are they interchangeable.

I noticed Japanese superhero shows seem to use both interchangeably, with Justirisers using 装着 and others like Gogov and Tomica Hero Rescue force use 着装.

Answer (score 4):

「装着{そうちゃく}」 and 「着装{ちゃくそう}」 should be interchangeable most of the time.  If I said otherwise, I would be fairly nitpicky.

If anything, 「着装」 is probably more often used to focus on the ***state*** of something attached to the main and/or larger object while 「装着」 may tend to focus more on the ***action*** of attaching something.  If you, however, asked me if this difference were of utmost importance, I would reply somewhat negatively.

Comment: Are there other instances of interchangeable word kanji combinations? Out of curiosity.

Comment: @keithmaxx https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48910/what-is-the-term-for-two-kanjis-that-when-written-in-reverse-have-the-same-me

Answer (score 3):

One obvious difference is that 装着 is far more common than 着装. On [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/), there are 1,186 hits for 装着 and only 41 hits for 着装 (including false-positive results such as 蒸着装置 "vapor disposition device"). Personally I am only familiar with 装着.

Judging from the results above and the dictionary definition, 着装 seems to be safely used with ordinary clothes and dresses at least in formal/academic contexts. In particular, 着物 (Japanese *kimono*) and 着装 seem to be often used together (for example [this](http://zenwasai.com/index.php?%E7%9D%80%E8%A3%85%E8%AA%8D%E5%AE%9A%E8%A9%A6%E9%A8%93)). On the other hand, from what I understand, 装着 is usually used with armors, protectors, seat belts, etc. Anyway, in superhero contexts, I guess they are basically interchangeable.

Some similar examples are found [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44246/5010). [There is even a book](https://www.kinokuniya.co.jp/f/dsg-01-9784873022680) written by a Japanese amateur kanji fan.