# How to describe switching individual 漢字？

Tags: words, kanji

Apologies if this question title is vague but, is there a word in Japanese that describes a new word which is formed by switching the 漢字 around?

e.g

> 例文 -> 文例
>
> 運命 -> 命運
>
> 合併 -> 併合

How do you describe this?

Comment: I think the answer is no. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/48927/7944

Comment: Also related: [Can a two Kanji character word ever have the same meaning if written in reverse order?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44242/5010) I doubt they were coined "by switching the 漢字 around", though.